# How to add picture from gallery or taken with camera into a ListView dinamically using 2 activities and a custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-camera, android-gallery

I have two activity:

1. First activity: MyCollectionActivity

In this activity I have a TextView for title, a ListView - to show my list of stamps and a FloatingButtonAction.

When I click on the FloatingButtonAction I want to start my second activity that I'm talking about: InsertStampActivity.

2. Second activity: InsertStampActivity

InsertStampActivity where I have 3 EditText (inserting country, value, year), an ImageButton and an empty ImageView(for the inserted image). When I click on the ImageButton it will pop up an AlertDialogBox with 3 buttons: Button - FROM GALLERY, Button - TAKE PHOTO or Button - EXIT.

When I click on FROM GALLERY I want to select a picture from my phone's gallery, when I click on TAKE PHOTO to open phone's camera to take photo and when I click on EXIT, to return to MyCollectionActivity.

For this to happend I want to use an CustomAdapter.

---**My problem is how to manage the inserted image.**---

My CLASS Timbru (meaning stamp):

```
public class Timbru implements Parcelable {

private Integer year;
private String country;
private Float value;
private String imagePath;

public Timbru(int year, String country, float value, String imagePath) {
    this.year = year;
    this.country = country;
    this.value = value;
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
}

public Timbru() {
}

public String getImagePath() {
    return imagePath;
}

public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
}

public Integer getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(Integer year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public Float getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(Float value) {
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Timbru{" +
            "year=" + year +
            ", country='" + country + '\'' +
            ", value=" + value +
            ", imagePath='" + imagePath + '\'' +
            '}';
}

public Timbru(Parcel in) {
    this.year = in.readInt();
    this.country = in.readString();
    this.value = in.readFloat();
}

public static Parcelable.Creator<Timbru> CREATOR = new Creator<Timbru>() {
    @Override
    public Timbru createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
        return new Timbru(parcel);
    }

    @Override
    public Timbru[] newArray(int i) {
        return new Timbru[i];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeInt(year);
    parcel.writeString(country);
    parcel.writeFloat(value);
    }  
}
```

This is a class for keeping the List:

```
public class ListaTimbru {

private static ArrayList<Timbru> timbre = new ArrayList<>();

public static ArrayList<Timbru> getTimbre() {
    return timbre;
}

public ListaTimbru() {

     }
}
```

This is TimbruAdapter class:

```
public class TimbruAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private int resource;
private List<Timbru> objects;
private LayoutInflater inflater;


public TimbruAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List objects, LayoutInflater inflater) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.inflater = inflater;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.objects = objects;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = inflater.inflate(this.resource, parent, false);

    TextView tvYear = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_year_rowLayout2);
    TextView tvCountry = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_country_rowLayout2);
    TextView tvValue = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_value_rowLayout2);

    Timbru timbru = objects.get(position);

    tvCountry.setText(timbru != null && timbru.getCountry() != null ? timbru.getCountry() : "");
    tvYear.setText(timbru != null && timbru.getYear() != null ? timbru.getYear().toString() : "");
    tvValue.setText(timbru != null && timbru.getValue() != null ? timbru.getValue().toString() : "");

    return row;
    }
 }
```

This is MyCollectionActivity:

```
public class MyColectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FloatingActionButton fltBtn_insert;
    ListView listViewStamps;
    List<String> listStamps = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Timbru> listStamps2 = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_colection);

    fltBtn_insert = (FloatingActionButton) 
    findViewById(R.id.flBtn_insertNewStamp_myCollection);
    listViewStamps = (ListView) 
    findViewById(R.id.lv_stampList_myCollection);

    TimbruAdapter adapter = new TimbruAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_layout2, ListaTimbru.getTimbre(), getLayoutInflater());
    listViewStamps.setAdapter(adapter);

    fltBtn_insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InsertStampActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.ADD_STAMP_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == Constants.ADD_STAMP_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Timbru result = data.getParcelableExtra(Constants.ADD_STAMP_KEY);
        if (result != null) {
            ListaTimbru.getTimbre().add(result);
            TimbruAdapter currentAdapter = (TimbruAdapter) listViewStamps.getAdapter();
            currentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

This is InsertStampActivity:

```
public class InsertStampActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText et_year;
EditText et_country;
EditText et_value;
Intent intent;
Button insertStamp;
ImageView poza_timbru;
Uri imageUri;
static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST=1;
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_TAKEN=2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_insert_stamp);
    initializareComponente();
    intent = getIntent();
}

private void initializareComponente() {
    et_year = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_year_insertStamp);
    et_country = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_country_insertStamp);
    et_value = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_value_insertStamp);
    poza_timbru = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView_stampAdded_insertStamp);

    insertStamp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_insertStamp);

    insertStamp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (validation()) {
                Timbru timbru = createTimbruFromComponents();
                if (timbru != null) {
                    intent.putExtra(ADD_STAMP_KEY, timbru);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private Timbru createTimbruFromComponents() {
    Integer year = Integer.parseInt(et_year.getText().toString());
    String country = et_country.getText().toString();
    Float value = Float.parseFloat(et_value.getText().toString());


    Uri selectedImage=intent.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    int columnIndex = 0;
    String picturePath = null;
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return new Timbru(year, country, value,picturePath);
}

private boolean validation() {
    //only for EditTexts
    if (et_year.getText() == null || et_year.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() || et_year.getText().toString().length() < 4) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Year is not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (et_country.getText() == null || et_country.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Country is not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (et_value.getText() == null || et_value.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value is not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return true;
}

public void imgBtn_insertImagine(View view) {

    //DIALOG BOX
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_box);
    dialog.setTitle("PICK ONE");
    Button exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExit_dialogBox);
    exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnForGallery_dialogBox).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openGallery();
        }
    });

    dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnTakePhoto_dialogBox).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openCamera();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}

public void openCamera() {
    Intent intentCamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (intentCamera.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        String fileName = "temp.jpg";
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
        imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        intentCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_TAKEN);
    }
}

public void openGallery() {
    Intent intentGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/*"); //arata doar imagini, nu si video sau altceva
    startActivityForResult(intentGallery, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST:
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                int columnIndex = 0;
                String picturePath = null;
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                }
                Timbru timbru = new Timbru();
                timbru.setCountry("Madagascar");
                timbru.setValue(20.4f);
                timbru.setImagePath(picturePath);
                timbru.setYear(1200);
                ListaTimbru.getTimbre().add(timbru);
            }
             break;
        case REQUEST_IMAGE_TAKEN:
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_TAKEN && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(imageUri, projection, null, null, null);
                int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
                Timbru timbru = new Timbru();
                timbru.setCountry("Australia");
                timbru.setValue(55.5f);
                timbru.setImagePath(picturePath);
                timbru.setYear(1800);
                ListaTimbru.getTimbre().add(timbru);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your R.layout.row_layout2 code? You are not using any imageview in listview child item.

Comment: @Mohamed Mohaideen AH I use an ImageView

Comment: In adapter class you have only three textview no imageview.

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH because i don;t know how to manage the photo. with ImageView or iwth it's path. that the whole point of my question. how to implement a picture received from gallery in my custom adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same Activity(InsertStampActivity) you can use this code to display image from camera & gallery to imageview

```
case REQUEST_IMAGE_TAKEN:
 if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_TAKEN && resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
 {
   Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
   poza_timbru.setImageBitmap(photo); //poza_timbru is your imageview.
 }
case PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST:
 if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) 
 {

   Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
   poza_timbru.setImageBitmap(thumbnail); //poza_timbru is your imageview.
 }
```

Then in adapter class view add one imageview in R.Layout.row_layout2 pass your data to adapter class then display it in listview.

Hope it helps..!